# How does protected view of word document protect my computer from virus?

Tags: microsoft-word, virus

How does protected view of word document protect my computer from virus?

Here MS Word 2013 claims:

[image]

I already open the document file, virus should attack my computer, but here it says protected view will keep computer from virus.

Comment: This is best answer by the detailed support article: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/What-is-Protected-View-d6f09ac7-e6b9-4495-8e43-2bbcdbcb6653

Comment: Here is a related [thread](https://superuser.com/questions/422379/office-protected-view-necessary-when-i-have-antivirus), maybe it could help you know more about Protected View.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The warning keeps the document from fully opening (no editing or printing) so that if the document is untrusted (you do not know its source) you can delete the document.

If the document is trusted (you know the source), you can click on Enable Edit and proceed normally.

It is not true virus protection - that is not its job. It is just a warning in the event an untrusted document comes to you. If the document contains a virus, and you open it, your computer would get the virus. Your on-board antivirus (Windows Defender for example) should catch this.